# Difference between different kinds of tree ADTs other than binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Apart from the binary and binary search trees; I am not sure what exactly is the fundamental difference between the following tree-based data structures. Are some of the trees simply a subset of another tree? Are some of the trees exactly the same but following different nomenclatures?

1. B-Tree
2. B+ Tree
3. k-ary tree
4. k-d tree
5. n-ary tree
6. quad tree
7. 2-3 tree
8. 2-3-4 tree
9. m-Tree
10. m-ary tree

The only trees that have a very clear definition and no overlapping are binary, binary search trees and perhaps even tries.

Apart from those, Google search results for the above listed trees lead to so many different definitions, some overlap, some are very different from each other. For example,  the implementation of a b-tree by one person is so different from another; that it literally calls for a change of definition. It's gotten to the point where all these definitions just started to confuse the heck out of me. Is there a book for all the above tree data structures that can be considered the standard bible? Some clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many of these are not ADTs at all. In fact, binary search trees are not an ADT, but a concrete data structure. The ADT they implement is either the dynamic set, or the associative map.

Comment: The closest to a 'standard' definition would be gotten from whomever created it (probably in a paper). But my guess is that you don't fully understand the definitions (and thus think there's a greater difference than there truly is), you are mistaking implementation details for definition details, or you're reading definitions written by those who have no idea what they're talking about or don't communicate well, because I'm familiar with most of those, and most of them have fairly straight-forward definitions. Oh, and [asking for a book is off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most, although possibly not all of these are in Aho, Hopcroft and Ullman's *Data Structures and Algorithms*

A hint is that anything with -ary in it's name is a tree with a defined branching degree - so a binary tree has two (possibly null) children per node; a n -ary tree has n (possibly null) children per node.

Most of the others in the list have some sort of balancing in their definition - and algorithms - to keep their worst case behaviour to O(n log n), whereas without balancing they typically have worst case behaviour of O(n^2)

A quad tree would be the exception, as it is a means of dividing space, used in graphics and image processing algorithms.